# How can I assert notification for a group of users?

Tags: laravel

I went through notification testing and have to check the notification routing but I have problem when it comes to group assertions. For a single receiver, all tests passes with the default `Notification::assertSentTo` method. But things were different when it goes to group notification. I have tried to swap between 3 approaches;

1. This approach gave a warning stating that `This test did not perform any assertions`

```php
$author->company->employees()->role('hrd')->each(function ($hrd) {
    Notification::assertSentTo($hrd, LeaveRequestNotification::class);
});
```

2. Same warning, but with `foreach`

```php
foreach($author->company->employees->role('hrd') as $hrd) {
    Notification::assertSentTo($hrd, LeaveRequestNotification::class);
}
```

3. `BadMethodCallException` with test going red.

```php
Notification::assertSentTo(
    $author->company->employees()->role('hrd'),
    LeaveRequestNotification::class,
);
```

Here is the complete error message occured by the 3rd approach

```
$ test --testsuite=Unit --filter=LeaveTest::testShouldSendRequestNotificationToHrdsWhenAuthorIsRegularEmployee --stop-on-failure

   FAIL  Tests\Unit\LeaveTest
  ⨯ should send request notification to hrds when author is regular employee

  ---

  • Tests\Unit\LeaveTest > should send request notification to hrds when author is regular employee       
   BadMethodCallException 

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::getKey()
```

So, what is the proper way for doing this?

Comment: Are you sure $author->company->employees->role('hrd') does not return an empty array?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, it wasn't empty when I `dd` it

Comment: ah wait lemme double check

Comment: Ah.. that's empty, what a silly mistake, I was `dd`-ing the relationship so I thought it was there, it prints 0 when I add `->count()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem, it was lying here on the `assignRole` loop, I used the wrong subject

```
$leave->company->employees
```

instead of

```
$author->company->employees
```

The loop:

```php
foreach ($leave->company->employees as $employee) {
    if (!$employee->hasRole('employee')) {
        $employee->assignRole('hrd');
    }
}

dd($author->company->employees()->role('hrd')->count()); // prints 0
```

I changed the subject and use the 3rd approach, only this time, I add `get()` after the role definition. Works fine with no error. Thanks for **@mrhn** for reminding me about the existence of the loop subject.

```php
foreach ($author->company->employees as $employee) {
    if (!$employee->hasRole('employee')) {
        $employee->assignRole('hrd');
    }
}

LeaveRequest::dispatch($leave);
Notification::assertSentTo(
    $author->company->employees()->role('hrd')->get(),
    LeaveRequestNotification::class,
);
```